# Error copy resources with become_user

Tags: ansible

I´m using become_user to change user once I connect to the remote machine
In this example ssh user1 copy the file into the remote machine, then we change user by user2 and we move the file.
Here the process and the final error that I have.

```
   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 
   ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'rc=flag; [ -r /tmp/profile-java ] || rc=2; [ -f /tmp/profile-java ] || rc=1; [ -d /tmp/profile-java ] && rc=3; python -V 2>/dev/null || rc=4; [ x"$rc" != "xflag" ] && echo "${rc} "/tmp/profile-java && exit 0; (python -c '"'"'import hashlib; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = hashlib.sha1(); afile = open("'"'"'/tmp/profile-java'"'"'", "rb") buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE) while len(buf) > 0: hasher.update(buf) buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE) afile.close() print(hasher.hexdigest())'"'"' 2>/dev/null) || (python -c '"'"'import sha; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = sha.sha(); afile = open("'"'"'/tmp/profile-java'"'"'", "rb") buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE) while len(buf) > 0: hasher.update(buf) buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE) afile.close() print(hasher.hexdigest())'"'"' 2>/dev/null) || (echo '"'"'0 '"'"'/tmp/profile-java)'


   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774 && echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774'


 <172.28.178.227> PUT /u01/app/jenkins/workspace/02_Customer-Order-Services/deploy-to-PPE/roles/jvm/files/profile-java.j2 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/source

   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/source'

   <172.28.178.227> PUT /tmp/tmpO9iYgq TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/copy

   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/copy'

   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'su svc-cos -c "/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-kifkfsbasxqszcorqwgpmcigwmalvwnq; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/copy'"'"'"'

   <172.28.178.227> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.28.178.227 /bin/sh -c 'rm -rf /tmp/ansible-tmp-1458229962.35-167690832134774/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

And then the final error, which is irrelevant because is just a python error. But I believe is a permissions issue.

```
  failed: [*********] => {"checksum": "f1f7d1e8f4fe6397dcc39fe4e2613b607e8c6fa1", "failed": true}
  msg: Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!
```

All python libraries are properly installed, and the scripts works fine, only it fails when I use become_user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the package is not installed for the second user. I had this problem when using virtualenv in python.

What you can do as a workaround is to manually move the content of: `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/` to wherever Anisble is trying to read the packages from. You can see this when using the -vvv option when executiong your playbook `ansible-playbook file -vvv`

For more info you can use this [Link](https://dmsimard.com/2016/01/08/selinux-python-virtualenv-chroot-and-ansible-dont-play-nice/)

Answer (score 1):

`target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed` is a pretty obvious error. Check if `libselinux-python` package is installed.

From the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html):

> Note
>
> If you have SELinux enabled on remote nodes, you will also want to install libselinux-python on them before using any copy/file/template related functions in Ansible. You can of course still use the yum module in Ansible to install this package on remote systems that do not have it.

Comment: like I said the error is not related with any python library, the scripts works pèrfectly fine without use become_user. Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe have a look at what SELinux is. It makes perfect sense why your task runs without the `become_user` argument, and not with it, which runs a sudo task on the host.